# Append unicode Items in python list

Tags: python

I want to test if a Unicode word that passed to the function isn't in the list, function do some manipulate on this word. something like this:

```
def my_function(word):
    if not word in [u'تست']:
    ...
```

well it works perfect. but my list is more bigger than this and I saved its words to a separate file. now I'm trying to read this file lines as words but I don't know how to append theme as Unicode like `[u'تست']`. I tried to use `unicode()` but even after that `if` condition can't find words that are already in the file.

Comment: *Unicode* is never written to a file directly. The data is always encoded using some encoding - usually utf-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the file using [`codecs.open`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) instead of `open`, then everything you read from the file will be `unicode` instead of `str`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. OK I opened the file with codecs and now my lists attributes are something like `u'\u06cc\u0648\u0647\u0627\n'` and my if condition still can't find my words in list!

Comment: @Shahinism the `\n` at the end is a newline; try removing it with `strip`.

Comment: Thank you for point to that. I removed that but still it can't find! my words are something like `تست` and of course it is Unicode but my words are u'\u06cc\u0648\u0647\u0627' can it be the problem?

Comment: @Shahinism `u'\u06cc\u0648\u0647\u0627'` is `یوها`; note that the ya is the Farsi ye, not the Arabic ya.

Comment: @Shahinism that is just a representation thing. `'\u06cc\u0648\u0647\u0627'` will always compare equal to `'یوها'`, and they will always be treated as the same (because they *are* the same). The former is just how Python writes it sometimes - much like `'\x61'` is a different way of writing `'a'`.

Comment: yes I want the Farsi one. @lvc OK this was my problem! but I still cant find the proper word! I have to find some other way to do it. thank you ;-)